# Long CRON command does not work, no matter how I use it

Tags: docker, cron, rpc

I've been fiddling a lot with a cron job, and so far I cannot make it work properly.

Here is the command:

```
docker exec mosquitto mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -u LOGIN -P PASSWORD -t rtorrent_ntorrents -m "{\"ntorrents\": $(docker exec -it box rtxmlrpc download_list "" | wc -l)}"
```

Here is what I tried:

- putting it in a cronjob to be executed every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/zsh -c 'docker exec mosquitto mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -u LOGIN -P PASSWORD -t rtorrent_ntorrents -m "{\"ntorrents\": $(docker exec -it box rtxmlrpc download_list "" | wc -l)}"'
```

-> fails

- put the command in a function in `.zshenv` or `.zshrc`, then create a CRON job launching the function -> fails
- I also tried setting up a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

while :
do
  docker exec mosquitto mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -u LOGIN -P PASSWORD -t rtorrent_ntorrents -m "{\"ntorrents\": $(docker exec -it box rtxmlrpc downl$
  sleep 60
done
```

Which fails this way:

```
[1] 8665
[1]  + 8665 suspended (tty output)  ./ntorrents
```

The *only* way I found to use my command in a background process is `screen`...

Of course, running the command itself in a shell produces the desired result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Should you be using `docker exec` with `-it` when running non-interactively from `crond`?

Comment: Oh stupid me...it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, removing the `-it` parameter solves the issue.